# Not Getting Desired Output From For Loop

Tags: python, for-loop

I have this code for a program that should manipulate certain inputs the user enters.

I'm not sure how to only get x number of ouputs (x is specified by the user at the start of the program).

```
numOfFloats = int(input("Enter the number of floating point inputs: "))
numOfInts = int(input("Enter the number of integer inputs: "))
numOfStrings = int(input("Enter the number of string inputs: "))

for num in range(numOfStrings,0,-1):
    print()

    ffloats = float(input("Enter a real number: "))
    iints = int(input("Enter an integer: "))
    string = input("Enter a string: ")

    print()

    print("float: ", ffloats**(1/10))
    print("int: ", iints**10)
    print("string: ", (string + string))
```

I get all three requests each time, even though I have specified in the beginning that I only want 1 float, 2 ints, and 3 strings. I get asked for 3 floats, 3 ints, and 3 strings. I do realize what my code does, but I'm not sure how to get it to where I want it. I have a feeling something is wrong in the for loop conditions.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The program did exactly what you told it to do: given the number of strings -- 3 -- get that many int-float-string sets.  You never used the other two quantities to control their loops.  You need three separate loops; here's the one for strings, with all the int and float stuff removed.

```
numOfStrings = int(input("Enter the number of string inputs: "))

for num in range(numOfStrings,0,-1):
    print()
    string = input("Enter a string: ")
    print()
    print("string: ", (string + string))
```

Now just do likewise for ints and floats, and I think you'll have what you want.

Yes, you can do it in one loop, but it's inelegant.  You have to find the max of all three numbers and use that as the loop's upper limit.  Within the loop, check "num" against the int, float, and string limits, each in turn.

This code would be less readable, harder to maintain, and slower.  Do you have some personal vendetta against loops?  :-)

Comment: Is there a way to do it all with just one for loop? I did realize I can just use another two loops to control the other types but I think there should be a way to do this with one for loop and some other conditions within it. Just not sure what?

Comment: Yes, but it's inelegant.

Answer (score 0):

```
ffloats = []
for num in range(numOfFloats):
    ffloats.append(float(input("\nEnter a real number: "))

iints = []
for num in range(numOfFloats):
    iints.append(int(input("\nEnter an integer: "))

sstrings = []
for num in range(numOfFloats):
    sstrings.append(input("\nEnter a real number: ")

print("Floats:", [f**(1/10) for f in ffloats])
print("Ints:", [i**10 for i in iints])
print("Strings:", [s + s for s in sstrings])
```

If you want them in order, then you'll have to:

```
for v in range(max([numOfFloats, numOfInts, numOfStrings])):
    if v < numOfFloats:
        ffloats.append(float(input("\nEnter a real number: "))
    if v < numOfInts:
        iints.append(int(input("\nEnter an integer: "))
    if v < numOfStrings:
        sstrings.append(input("\nEnter a string: ")
```

Answer (score 0):

If your really want just a single loop, then I would suggest you use a `while` loop rather than a `for` loop, as you need to keep looping until all values have been entered.

```
numOfFloats = int(input("Enter the number of floating point inputs: "))
numOfInts = int(input("Enter the number of integer inputs: "))
numOfStrings = int(input("Enter the number of string inputs: "))

while numOfFloats + numOfInts + numOfStrings:
    print()

    if numOfFloats:
        ffloats = float(input("Enter a real number: "))

    if numOfInts:
        iints = int(input("Enter an integer: "))

    if numOfStrings:
        string = input("Enter a string: ")

    print()

    if numOfFloats:
        print("float: ", ffloats**(1/10))
        numOfFloats -= 1

    if numOfInts:
        print("int: ", iints**10)
        numOfInts -= 1

    if numOfStrings:
        print("string: ", (string + string))
        numOfStrings -= 1
```

So for example:

```
Enter the number of floating point inputs: 1
Enter the number of integer inputs: 2
Enter the number of string inputs: 3

Enter a real number: 1.5
Enter an integer: 2
Enter a string: three

float:  1.0413797439924106
int:  1024
string:  threethree

Enter an integer: 2
Enter a string: hello

int:  1024
string:  hellohello

Enter a string: world

string:  worldworld
```